# Как отследить событие конца отрисовки dom?

Tags: javascript

Есть input для ввода json-schema из которой потом генерируются формочки. Схема очень большая и при нажатии на кнопку "генерировать" происходит задержка. Причина задержки: отрисовка dom. 
Я пытаюсь добавить loader. 
Сама функция-обработчик кнопки "генерировать" - работает быстро, и когда я пытаюсь навесить стили, что бы показать и скрыть лоадер оно не срабатывает, т.к. оно очень быстро выполняется и пользователь просто не замечает этого. 
Вопрос: есть ли какой-нибудь способ отследить событие конца отрисовки dom?

Это обработчик нажатия на кнопку:

```
 $('#loader').addClass('active-loader');

 try {
     schema = JSON.parse($schema.value);
 }
 catch (e) {
     alert('Invalid Schema: ' + e.message);
     return;
 }
 // Вызывается метод, который перерисовывает DOM из json-schema
 // json-schema большая. 1.5к строк
 reload();

 // Проблема в том, что эта строка отрабатывает быстрее чем перестроится dom      
 // Это происходит мгновенно. 
 $('#loader').removeClass('active-loader');
```

Проблема в том, что reload() отрабатывает быстро и loader сразу ныкается. Но dom еще перерисовывается, хотя функции уже отработали

Comment: Добавьте код страницы с комментами, что в каком порядке и как работает

Comment: Добавил код, можете посмотреть

Comment: а нельзя `$('#loader').removeClass('active-loader');` в конце `reload()` поставить?

Comment: Нет. Тут сама функция быстро отрабатывает. Проблема в перерисовки dom

Comment: Проблема в том, что `reload()` работает _асинхронно_. Как следствие. `removeClass()` отрабатывает _до_ окончания перерисовки. Нужно ковырять код `reload()` (как минимум ту часть, что отвечает за перерисовку).

Comment: А `reload()` работает с DOM всей страницы или какой-то отдельной частью? Да, хотелось бы иметь какое-то минимальное представление о том, что собcветнно делает функция `reload()` с DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Что, если рендерить не в DOM, а в переменную, и всё это время показывать «загружается..». А вставка уже отрендеренного html формы в родительский элемент, должно быть, гораздо быстрее, чем живой рендер по одному элементу в DOM напрямую?

**P.s.** Сомневаюсь, что именно отрисовка занимает какое-то заметное время. Но даже если так – может, просто подобрать «на глаз» и наивно ставить `setTimeout()`?

**P.p.s.** Есть события, вне стандартов, специфичные для бразуеров, которые используются в девелоперских тулзах для оценки эффективности рендеринга страниц, в основном. Но вы можете попробовать использовать их у себя. Напр. для Mozilla это событие [`MozAfterPaint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/MozAfterPaint) – когда окончилась именно очередная отрисовка.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно дать *правильный* ответ, не зная что делает Ваша функция reload, но, как вариант, в эту самую функцию можно передать callback, закрывающий loader, либо же поместить логику loader'а в саму функцию reload.

Если же в этой функции используется location.reload, то прочтите ответы на [следующий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553625/window-location-reload-complete).

Надеюсь, мой ответ поможет Вам разобраться с проблемой. Удачи!